# What is the best way to call same method in every class?

Tags: c#, wpf, class, generics

In every page in my WPF App, I need to valid if the user enter a valid date in the textbox or not.

I have 5 pages, and then, 5 methods where I valid my date with a little method.

I want to know what is the best solution/way to create a generic method callable in every page/class to valid my date?

```
public bool IsValidDate(string date)
{
    var regex = @"^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(date, regex); 

        return match.Success;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: couldn't you just make a public method?  Perhaps in a separate class...

Comment: As an aside, this regex will still allow invalid dates that 'look' like dates (like 31 Feb).  Why not use `DateTime.TryParse`?

Comment: I work with ViewModel, and every viewmodel dosen't have the instance of the other viewmodels. Public method not possible.

Comment: @Naografix it is possible because this method requires no context from the instance. It could easily be a public static method in another class.

Comment: @CharlesMager Thank you, going to use TryParse, it's better :) !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new class that contains helper functions like this:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static bool IsValidDate(string date)
    {
        var regex = @"^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(date, regex); 

            return match.Success;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from anywhere like:

```
if (Helper.IsValidDate(someDateString))
    // Bleh
```

Comment: This is my first solution, and I think I'm going to use it ^^

Answer (score 3):

Create an extension method on whatever class you are using for your date.

I strongly recommend not using strings to store dates because they have a tendency to cause runtime errors.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be a good fit for this specific example (this seems to belong in a helper/utility class like another answer suggests), but you can share a method among all pages by inheriting from a base class:

```
public abstract class BaseWindow : Window {
    protected static bool IsValidDate(string date) {
        // Do your stuff...
    }
}

// This is your actual WPF page class - when Visual Studio builds it, just change the 
// inheritance from "Window" to "BaseWindow"
public partial class MyWindow : BaseWindow {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a helper class like one of the other answers, or inherit from a base class and implement it there. Than inherit that class from the original class.

The reasons for a utility versus base class can be:

- The validation belongs typically to that screen and you probably don't need it elsewhere. Than it is more comfortable to use a base class/inheritance.
- If you want to use the validation mechanism also in other cases, put it in a helper class.
- Using the inheritance mechanism, keep in mind the validation class needs to have some WPF/GUI imports, so using it in a console app later can be tricky (thus use a helper instead).

Answer (score 1):

I would say that validating the date is close to being business logic and should therefore not be done directly on any page. It should be handled in the business layer.

EDIT: I take back my answer. itsme86 is correct. This is more of utility function.